# how to run python brew commands on windows7

Tags: python

I successfully installed brew on my windows 7PC,however I still cant run brew commands like `brew cleanup`,i dont seem to find any brew executable either,can anyone provide guidance on how to run brew commands on windows7?

```
pip install brew Collecting brew 
Downloading brew-0.1.3.zip (42kB) 100% |################################| 51kB 1.4MB/s 
Installing collected packages: brew Running setup.py install for brew ... done
Successfully installed brew-0.1.3
```

ERROR:-

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\brew>brew cleanup
'brew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: did you add it to your path?

Comment: uhhh brew != homebrew???

Comment: enderland - which path does it get installed to? I see a folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\brew`,is that where it gets installed?I already have C:\Python27 in my path

Comment: juanpa.arrivillage - not sure what that means,do you know from which folder I should run the brew commands?do you have any pointers?

Comment: @JeffShort 1) homebrew is a mac package manager you should not be trying to install it on windows, and 2) python brew is not homebrew, aka brew, the mac package manager

Comment: so ,how do I run `brew cleanup` and  `brew postinstall python` on windows 7 then?

Comment: `Homebrew` is not a Windows utility. You installed a machine-learning related library called `brew`, not the Mac `Homebrew` package manager. Why don't you try looking up "windows package managers"